# Bash evaluation using crazy passwords

Tags: strings, bash

I have some code that is loading passwords from AWS SSM and then using them through the script. I am really concerned that some funky password character is going to be used that is going to get interpreted/escaped/munged by bash. The code in question is below. Are there any obvious problems here? Can I improve this so that **no password** can trip this up?

```
updateEnvFile() {
    local user=$1
    local pass=$2
    local host=$3

    cat "${bin}/../environments/development.properties" |
    sed "s;url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mysql;url=jdbc:mysql://$host/mysql;" |
    sed "s/username=root/username=$user/" | sed "s/password=my-secret-pw/password=$pass/"
}

updateConfig() {
    local dbs=$1
    for db in ${dbs}; do
        local user=${params["/databases/migrate/${env}/${db}.user"]}
        local pass=${params["/databases/migrate/${env}/${db}.password"]}
        local host=${params["/databases/migrate/${env}/${db}.host"]}
        updateEnvFile "${user}" "${pass}" "${host}" > "${bin}/../environments/${db}.properties"
    done
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really pass a single argument with space-separated names to `updateConfig` like this?:

```
updateConfig "db1 db2 db3"
```

It would be simpler to let the function accept any number of arguments, then the loop becomes simply

```
for db
do
    #...
done
```

(`in "$@"` is inferred)

---

I'm not a fan of the repetition of `/databases/migrate/${env}/${db}` - consider a `local` variable for that:

```
local basepath="/databases/migrate/$env/$db"
for db; do
    local user=${params["$basepath.user"]}
    local pass=${params["$basepath.password"]}
    local host=${params["$basepath.host"]}
    updateEnvFile "$user" "$pass" "$host" >"$bin/../environments/$db.properties"
done
```

---

When substituting shell variables using sed `s` command, be sure to transform the replacement to quote any backslashes or separators in the substitution:

```
updateEnvFile() {
    local user=${1//\\/\\\\}
    local pass=${2//\\/\\\\}
    local host=${3//\\/\\\\}

    sed -e "/^url=/s;localhost;${host//;/\\;};" \
        -e  "/^username=/s;=.*;=${user//;/\\;};" \
        -e "/^password=/s;=.*;=${pass//;/\\;};" \
        "$bin/../environments/development.properties"
}
```

I've also combined your long pipeline into a singled `sed` invocation, and simplified each replacement to separate the matching and replacement parts.

Comment: The number of databases in question is discovered from the SSM params. So, it looks for anything with `$basePath/(db[0-9]+)` - literal code for that: `echo "${!params[@]}" | tr " " "\n" | sed 's;.*\(db[0-9]\).*;\1;' | sort| uniq`

I am going to see about what you have and apply it

Comment: I tried your example: The syntax for declaring user/pass/host isn't right. I am using bash v4

Comment: If I've made an error, please go ahead and propose a correction.  Thanks.

Comment: I would if I was sure exactly how it worked! :)

Answer (score 2):

That `cat` is entirely unnecessary. Also, multiple pipes to `sed` are redundant.

`sed` by design can take [a single long expression](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229234) and process the data.

As for your delimiters, I'd suggest using non-printable characters when in `sed`:

```
SED_DELIM=$(echo -en "\001")
```

and then:

```
sed "s${SED_DELIM}url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mysql${SED_DELIM}url=jdbc:mysql://$host/mysql${SED_DELIM}; s${SED_DELIM}username=root${SED_DELIM}username=$user${SED_DELIM}; s${SED_DELIM}password=my-secret-pw${SED_DELIM}password=$pass${SED_DELIM}" $file_name
```

Now, that looks quite long. You can evaluate individual expressions:

```
sed -e "s${SED_DELIM}url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mysql${SED_DELIM}url=jdbc:mysql://$host/mysql${SED_DELIM};" \
-e "s${SED_DELIM}username=root${SED_DELIM}username=$user${SED_DELIM};" \
-e "s${SED_DELIM}password=my-secret-pw${SED_DELIM}password=$pass${SED_DELIM}" \
$file_name
```

I'll go ahead and also use back-references:

```
sed -e "s${SED_DELIM}\(url=jdbc:mysql://\)localhost\(/mysql\)${SED_DELIM}\1$host\2${SED_DELIM};" \
-e "s${SED_DELIM}\(username=\)root${SED_DELIM}\1$user${SED_DELIM};" \
-e "s${SED_DELIM}\(password=\)my-secret-pw${SED_DELIM}\1$pass${SED_DELIM}" \
$file_name
```

Comment: It didn't even occur to me that sed might choke on something but a slash is entirely within the realm of password chars that might be chosen. Thanks! I was thinking more like bash and ""  doing weird things

Comment: Portable sed command lines have exactly one command per `-e` argument (writing `;` in place of the newline is a common, but not universal, extension to POSIX).  Also, given this is Bash, `$'\001'` is simpler than your `echo` command (but I don't agree with your recommendation not to simply use distinct characters for the delimiters; I like `!` or `#` when `/` is unsuitable, others choose `,` - instead, make the variables safe for interpolation, e.g. `s!pattern!${replacement//!/\!}!`)